# Undefined method 'to_key' error using form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I am getting the following error when trying to use form_for in my Rails application:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<Table::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x8a09ca8>
```

My config/routes.rb is:

```
root 'welcome#index'
post 'foo', as: 'foo', to: 'welcome#index'
```

The controller is:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

    def index
       @tables = Table.all
    end

    def test
      @tables = Table.all
    end

end
```

And the welcome/index.html.erb view is:

```
<p>
    <%= form_for @tables, :url => foo_path do |t| %>
    <%= t.text_area :name %>
    <% end %>
</p>
```

I've tried to do the url workaround that had been suggested in the documentation, but I'm still getting the same error.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I would like to understand this bug a bit more so I can better deal with it.

Comment: to start with rails refer this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code, `index` is returning a collection. However your view tries to define a form for it. This is unlikely going to be succeed.

Form is for an object, not for collections.

Perhaps you can do something like

```
def new 
  @table = Table.new
end
```

and in `new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @table do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And if you would like to stick with `index.html.erb` with a form. Then you have to edit your routes for index action and also in controller it should be for creating a new object.

```
def index
  @table = Table.new
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I called Table.new in the index action and it works! Now it makes sense to me. Using Table.all passes form_for a collection of objects, which does not work, but using Table.new correctly passes it a singular object. Conversely, I am expecting that using a method like .each on something like Table.new would not work either. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see your code have 3 not true things 
As RESFUL standard then:

- index action always go through with get action so in route file you should define again same that:

  `root "wellcome#index"
  get "foo", to: "wellcome#index", as: :foo`
- form_for usually use with model object but not collect as you use @tables, if model object not save into database form_for using to create 1 object to database, otherwise form_for using update that object
- if you want create form at index action you can follow me:
  `def index
  @tables = Table.all
  @table = Table.new
  end`

  index.html.erb file 

  `<%= form_for @table do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>`

  you need create tables_controller to process request from form send to server. you run:   
  `rails g controller tables`
  In table_controller.rb you write same as:

  `def create
  @table = Table.new table_params
  if @table.save 
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "success"
  else
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "fail"
  end
  end`

private
def table_params
  params.require(:table).permit :name
end

so that. end. Have nice day!